# JBoss jar library files

Tags: jboss, jar

In JBoss, if you have an ear archive file, the way to tell the environment the place 
of the lib folder, where it can find the library files, is the application.xml file.

Now I splitted the ear file into separate .war and .jar files. I do not have an ear folder anymore, so I deploy the war and jars directly in JBoss.

In the war archive I have the html and servlet files. In the jar archive I have the bean files. Now the library files are just needed by the java beans, not by the servlets.

So I need a folder in the .jar file to put the lib files and a way to tell the system the place of this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your jar libraries inside an ejb-jar: you can't, the standard specification doesn't allow you to have a jar inside another jar. Maybe some vendors provide specific solutions for that, but those are not standard. The standard solution would be to place all the related jars inside an ear. What you can do, and it's standard, is placing library jars inside the WEB-INF/lib directory of a war; but ejb-jar don't provide a similar structure.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I used to have this structure, but NOW I do not have any ear archive any more, just 2: one jar and one war.

Comment: I know this lib directory. Is there no way to have the libs bundled together with the other files in the jar archive?

Comment: Thank you Toni for you next to last comment. If put this commonent directly in your answer I could pick this one as the right answer for me.

Comment: Understood now :-) And no, the standard specification doesn't allow you to have a jar inside another jar. Maybe some vendors provide specific solutions for that, but those are not standard. The standard solution would be place all the related jars inside an ear. What you can do, and it's standard, is placing library jars inside the WEB-INF/lib directory of a war; but ejb-jar don't provide a similar structure.

Comment: Hi Wolfanfg, I've posted the comment in the answer. Some time ago, I wondered, as you have done, if there was any standard way to achive that. You can find some more information googling: "libraries inside an ejb-jar"